# Groovy paginate problem

Tags: groovy, gsp, pagination

I have an application written in groovy and I am having problems with the pagination of a resulting set.

I have a Controller called **ReportingController**. This controller has two methods called
**listdoiTln** and **listdoiEv**. Both methods are similar and at the end both have to render a list of reports. The last lines of both are as follows:

```
params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.max.toInteger() : 15,  100)             
render (view: 'list', model:[reportingInstanceList: reportingInstanceList, reportingInstanceTotal: i])
```

The list view is rendered as expected. At the footer of the **list.gsp** file I have:

```
<div class="paginateButtons">
    <g:paginate controller="reporting" total="${reportingInstanceTotal}" max="25"/></div>
</div>
```

The **list** is working, the buttons for the pagination are there but it is always displayed the whole collection. Notice that I do not have files callled **listdoiTln.gsp** or **listdoiEv.gsp**. I am using **list.gsp** with different data models.

Surely I am doing something wrong.

Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Luis

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with this, too, for quite a while.  Try this:

Evaluate param.offset in the controller:

`params.offset = params?.offset?.toInteger() ?: 0`

Include the params in the model:

`render (view: 'list', 
       model:[reportingInstanceList: reportingInstanceList, 
              reportingInstanceTotal: i,
              params: params])`

Check whether the value of `reportingInstanceTotal` is the value that you expect.  That tripped me up for a while.

If it still doesn't work, let me know, or try looking at one of the list.gsp pages and its associated controller that are generated by the `grails generate-all` command.

The paginate buttons are quite cool, but there is little documentation and it takes longer than I expected to set them up.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Unfortunately it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I went back to my code to figure out what else should be done and added new instructions to my answer.  Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. Unfortunately it didn't help. The whole list is displyed. I've added -as debuggin- following lines at the list.gsp: ${reportingInstanceTotal} - ${max} - ${params.offset}. The buttons are displayed but the whole list is there. Also at every column the links for sorting  don't work. (+1) for your help.

Comment: I'll keep looking for a reason the whole list keeps appearing.  For the column sorting links, there isn't room in a comment to explain how I got them to work.  If you create a question I can post the code.  Thanks for the +1.